# Tcpdump advanced filters

Tags: tcpdump, filter

i want ask for command can  Get only the IPs have more then 1 connection with different source port

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:X | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:Y (example)

if IP1 has connection to server with  Src Port X  and IP1 has another Connection with SourcePort Y

tcpdump will print the IP for as Filter condition

can tcpdump do this or can use another tool ?

Comment: check tshark/wireshark

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, as tcpdump filters are based on each packet as it comes in. To the best of my knowledge, tcpdump does not have any awareness of other packets that have come in and can't base capture/not-capture decisions based on what else has been seen. Filters grab specific packets based on the contents of each packet as it comes in.

You will have to use another analytic tool to find what you're looking for.

Comment: can you provide me some tools can be function ?

Comment: @extrem Unfortunately, I don't know. All of my work is between known endpoints, I haven't had to get familiar with the more sophisticated network monitors.